# How can I count no. of holes in an image and measure their diameter using matlab morphological operators?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So I have a graylevel image that demonstrates an electronic circuit card and I'm supposed to inspect the number of holes and the diameter of the holes, and I'm also allowed to use morphology operators in Matlab. The image is as follows:

[image: pcb.jpg]

I could wrote some codes that can count number of holes, but I don't know how to measure their diameters!

```
clear; close all; clc; warning off

im = imread('input\pcb.jpg');
im1 = im2bw(im,0);
% im1 = ~im2bw(im,0);
figure; imshow(im1);

strel1 = strel('disk',2);
im2 = imclose(im1,strel1);
figure; imshow(im2);

im3 = imfill(im2,'holes');
figure; imshow(im3);

im4 = im3 & ~im1;
figure; imshow(im4);

strel2 = strel('disk',3);
im5 = imopen(im4,strel2);
figure; imshow(im5);

[~,numCC] = bwlabel(im5);
fprintf('Number of holes equals:\t%d\n',numCC);
```

I appreciate any comments in advance!

Comment: Show us what you tried. You cant just ask "please do my work" in here

Comment: Sorry Bro.! I just tried so many morphology operators like opening and closing! but I didn't get any promising result! In addition I don't know how to use hit-miss operator in matlab! I mean how am I supposed to create background and foreground structural elements!?

Comment: use open a few times, then bwpropfilt to filter the 'roundest' objects and their positions. Then seed each of them and isolate them like [this](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/gradientweight.html#examples)

Comment: Would the total number of "holes" here be 4?

Comment: Yes! as it seems the total number of holes should be counted as 4!

Comment: Guys! I just revised my question above! Please reply if it's possible! Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I just wrote some code, and it seems that it's working somehow perfect!
Actually the number of holes are counted as 4 and their diameters are not precise ones but they're approximated using built-in MATLAB functions. The thing is that one of the holes is not separated distinctly! and it makes the results estimated ...

```
clear; close all; clc; warning off

im = imread('input\pcb.jpg');
level = graythresh(im);
imBin = im2bw(im,level);
figure(1); imshow(imBin); title('Binarized Original Image');
imBinInv = ~imBin;
figure(2); imshow(imBinInv); title('Inverted Binarized Original Image');

imInvHolSep = imdilate(imerode(imBinInv,strel('disk',21)),strel('disk',23));
figure(3); imshow(imInvHolSep); title('Inverted Holes Separated');

imInHolSepBound = imInvHolSep & ~imerode(imInvHolSep,strel('disk',2));
figure(4); imshow(imInHolSepBound); title('Inverted Holes Boundaries');

imInvHolSepFill = imfill(imInHolSepBound,'holes');
figure(5); imshow(imInvHolSepFill); title('Inverted Holes Filled After Setting Boundaries');

imInvHolSepDist = imerode(imInvHolSepFill,strel('disk',1));
figure(6); imshow(imInvHolSepDist); title('Inverted Holes Eroded Just For The Case of Indistinct Hole');

imInvHolSepMinus = imInvHolSepDist & ~imBin;
figure(7); imshow(imInvHolSepMinus); title('Inverted Holes Minus The Inverted Binarized Image');

imInvHolSepSmooth = imdilate(imInvHolSepMinus,strel('disk',2));
figure(8); imshow(imInvHolSepSmooth); title('Final Approximated Inverted Holes Smoothed');

[~,numCC] = bwlabel(imInvHolSepSmooth);
fprintf('Number of holes equals:\t%d\n',numCC);

stats = regionprops(imInvHolSepSmooth);
centroid = zeros(length(stats),2);
area = zeros(length(stats),1);
for c1 = 1:length(stats)
    centroid(c1,:) = stats(c1).Centroid;
    area(c1) = stats(c1).Area;
    fprintf('Diameter of the hole with centroid coordinates [%.2f, %.2f] is:\t%.2f\n',centroid(c1,1),centroid(c1,2),sqrt(area(c1)/pi));
end
```